# Trying to use char* as parameter in C++

Tags: c++

I have this function:

```
void ReadFile(std::string fileName, char* buffer) {
    std::ifstream infile(fileName);

    infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
    long size = infile.tellg();
    infile.seekg(0);

    buffer = new char[size];

    infile.read(buffer, size);
    infile.close();

    return;
}
```

And I'm trying to call it this way:

```
char buffer;
ReadFile("file.txt", &buffer);

std::cout << buffer;
```

And All I got is: nothing.

Does anyone could help me?

Comment: Well a single `char` is a poor buffer.

Comment: And modifying a local parameter (the `buffer` in your function) won't show any effect outside of that function ...

Comment: `buffer = new char[size];` just changes the copy of the address parameter. You need a `char*` outside and a `char*&` as parameter.

Comment: First, you need to pass a `char**` to a `ReadFile`, cause it will modify the address of the buffer (with `new`). Or use reference, as πάντα ῥεῖ suggests.

Comment: Thanks for all you guys! I fixed it using πάντα ῥεῖ sugestion! :)

Comment: @GuilhermeChiara Glad to help you. I'd rather suggest to use a `std::string` or `std::vector<uint8_t>` as buffer though.

Comment: Nah, just return a pointer or an `std::string`. Output parameters are eew.

Comment: @juanchopanza `std::vector<uint8_t>` seems more appropriate for that IMO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, could be. Anything but an output parameter!